# Lewis Carroll is confusing me

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was skimming through "Information Security" by Mark Stamp. Each chapter has some weird (but, nice) quote. Today, I came across something *inconceivable*. It said,

> *"... if you'd like it, put more simply - Never imagine yourself not to be otherwise than what it might appear to others that what you were or might have been was not otherwise than what you had been would have appeared to them to be otherwise."* - Lewis Carroll (Alice in Wonderland)

I don't understand how that's simple. Is there a better way to grasp this *horror*?

Comment: Have you quoted it with proper punctuation marks?

Comment: @Man_From_India: Nah, this is how they've quoted in that book :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a joke.

In the original this reads (the emphasis is mine, not Carroll's):

> I quite agree with you. And the moral of that is: **Be what you would seem to be**, or if you'd like it put more simply: Never imagine yourself not to be otherwise than what it might appear to others that what you were or might have been was not otherwise than what you had been would have appeared to them to be otherwise.

Lewis Carroll was by profession a mathematician and student of logic, and was very fond of incorporating logical puzzles and allusions into his works. Here he is poking fun at the very subtle and complicated forms into which a logician has to cast apparently ‘simple’ natural-language utterances in order to deal with strict logical meaning. Real Linguists, too, are frequently compelled to express themselves this way; but their tongues are not usually in their cheeks.

There are amusing discussions of this passage [here](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst31223_Never-imagine-yourself-not-to-be-otherwise-than-what----.aspx) and [here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001380.html) and [here](http://languagehat.com/the-simplicity-of-the-dutchess/).

Comment: To put it another way: if Lewis Carroll does not confuse you then you are not reading him carefully enough! (It does not follow however that if he does confuse you then you are reading him carefully.) He has not succeeded completely if he is incapable of confusing you somewhat.

Comment: Ah... Now, I think I should take the bold text and simply *neglect* the other. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It's true that the sentence could be mind-boggling at first, but my opinion is that the sentence is **not difficult**, but it's **structurally complicated**. It's not difficult in the sense that it has any difficult words or phrases. (The use of *[otherwise than](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/otherwise-than)* could be a bit unfamiliar, though.) What really makes it difficult is its syntax.

To understand my point, consider this shorter example:

> *The rat the cat the dog chased chased ran away.*

It's a rather short sentence, and it has only plain words--no difficult phrase or idiom, but it should make you think a little to understand its meaning. (Hint: *The rat that the cat chased ran away.*)

---

This answer wants to show you that we can understand the sentence straightforwardly. But first, let's simplify the sentence a little with a few simple substitutions:

> ORIGINAL: *Never imagine yourself not to be otherwise than what it might appear to others that what you were or might have been was not otherwise than what you had been would have appeared to them to be otherwise.*
>
> SIMPLIFIED: *Never imagine yourself **to be anything else but** what it might appear to others that what you were or might have been was not **different from** what you had been would have appeared to them to be otherwise **(which wouldn't be what you had been)**.*

Here is its structure:

```
Never imagine yourself to be [
  anything else but [
    what it might appear to others that [
      [ what you were or might have been ]
        was not different from [
          [ what you had been ]
            would have appeared
              to them
              to be otherwise (
                which wouldn't be
                  [ what you had been ]
              )
        ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

or in exact words according to original text:

```
Never imagine yourself to be [
  otherwise than [
    what it might appear to others that [
      [ what you were or might have been ]
        was not otherwise than [
          [ what you had been ]
            would have appeared
              to them
              to be otherwise
        ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I hope that the meaning of the sentence should now be self-evident.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence itself is actually grammatically sound, it's just that he applies a kind of enthymematic structure to his grammar which makes it appear more complicated than it is and as though it were flawed.

The original sentence is as follows: "...never imagine yourself to be otherwise than what it might appear to others that you were or might have been was not otherwise than what you had been would have appeared to them to be otherwise."

Now, the first confusing bit is "... or might have been *was* not..."
The second confusing bit is "... than what *you had been would have* appeared..."

Having recognized these two bits, slightly rephrasing these two peculiarities and altering some of the syntax will lead to a clearer sentence.

Viz., "Never imagine yourself to be other than what it might appear to others that you were or might have been were you not other than what you would have been had you appeared to them, otherwise, to be."

This can be simplified in a way which retains the same meaning.

Viz., "Always imagine yourself to be as to others you appear; never imagine how you might appear otherwise."